# Кодировка в Android + MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql, кодировка

Задача такая: приложение принимает введенные пользователем данные (создается событие) и пишет их во внешнюю БД с помощью php скриптов на сервере, затем отображает эти данные.
Принимаются на русском. Если создаю событие в приложении, то в нем все хорошо, а в БД белиберда. Если создаю в БД, то в БД все хорошо, а в приложении знаки вопроса.
Вроде везде все в utf-8

формируем:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... v) {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_TITLE, title);
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_DATE, date);
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_TIME, time);
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_ADDRESS, address);
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
            params.put(Config.EVENTS_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, description);

            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(Config.URL_ADD, params);
            return result;
        }
```

соединяемся:

```
public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String response;

            while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(response);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$title = $_POST['title'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

if($title == '' || $date == '' || $time == '' || $address == '' || $phone == '' || $description == ''){
echo 'Заполните все поля, пожалуйста';
}else{

require_once('db_connect.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO events_tab (title,date,time,address,phone,description) VALUES ('$title','$date','$time','$address','$phone','$description')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
echo 'Событие добавлено';
}else{
echo 'Событие не добавлено';
}

mysqli_close($con);
}
}
?>
```

кодировка БД (это ведь оно? я не путаю?):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

файл подключения:

```
<?php
define('HOST', 'localhost:3306'); // db server
define('USER', 'пользователь'); // db user
define('PASS', 'пароль'); // db password 
define('DB', 'базаданных'); // db name
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

Comment: Скорее всего дело в php, а точнее в том, как вы там создаёте подключение к БД - покажите это место. Ну и покажите также настройки кодидовки самой БД

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавлено

Comment: А что в переменной `$con`? Там как прописана кодировка? Осторожнее - не выложите сучайно логин-пароль от БД

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавила, что-то мне подсказывает, что она здесь никак не прописана

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте задать кодировку подключения к БД [так](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.set-charset.php):

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

Или вот так, используя `pdo`:

```
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass ";

$db = "db";
$host = "host";
$charset = "utf8";

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array
    (
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

Comment: Магнифико, большое спасибо